# SQL records with the same date

Tags: sql

**I have data as follows:**

```
id  bilgi   yayin_tarihi
40  veri    2014-06-10
39  veri2   2014-06-10
38  veri3   2014-06-08
37  veri4   2014-06-08
36  veri5   2014-05-18
37  veri6   2014-05-18
34  veri7   2014-05-18
```

**I this how my data is combined in this way?**

```
id  bilgi           yayin_tarihi 
40  veri,veri2      2014-06-10   
38  veri3,veri4     2014-06-08
36  veri6,veri7     2014-05-18
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What database type? Mysql / Oracle / sql server?

Comment: In Postgres you can use `string_agg()`, in Oracle you can use `listagg()` in MySQL you can use `group_concat()` together with a `group by` statement. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution that comes up with the desired results is:

```
select max(id) as max, group_concat(bilgi order by bilgi) as bilgi, yayin_tarihi
from table t
group by yayin_tarihi
order by yayin_tarihi desc;
```